# How to get test device id for testing Admob on iOS in Unity3D

Tags: ios, admob, adsense

I am implementing AdMob in an iOS Games, using UNITY3D and want to know if there is any way to get Device Hash ID (to be used in AdMob) directly from Unity or any other way without Xcode. The condition is that I want to demo AdMob to client and he is not having mac/xcode, so how do get the device id which I can put in test devices list for admob.

For Android I found [one app on play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pe.go_com.admobdeviceidfinder&hl=en) which works fine but not getting it for iOS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a "hashed device id" for testing admob on ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24760150/how-to-get-a-hashed-device-id-for-testing-admob-on-ios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just compute the MD5 of the advertising identifier and use it as your test device id - [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24760150/how-to-get-a-hashed-device-id-for-testing-admob-on-ios)

Here is [apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AdSupport/Reference/ASIdentifierManager_Ref/) to get the advertising identifier. Check section `Getting the Advertising Identifier`

> The [ASIdentifierManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AdSupport/Reference/ASIdentifierManager_Ref/) class provides apps with access to an
>   identifier that can be used only for serving advertisements, as well
>   as a flag which indicates whether a user has limited ad tracking.
>
> This class is expected to be used by developers who are implementing a
>   system for serving ads. These organizations typically provide app
>   developers with the code that interacts with this class. App
>   developers may need to link against the Ad Support framework to use
>   that code, but they should not need to interact with the
>   ASIdentifierManager class directly.
>
> To get the advertising identifier:
>
> 1. Get a reference to the shared instance of this class using the
>      sharedManager method.
> 2. Check whether advertising tracking is limited using the
>      advertisingTrackingEnabled property.
>
> If the user has limited ad tracking, use the advertising identifier
>   only for the following purposes: frequency capping, attribution,
>   conversion events, estimating the number of unique users, advertising
>   fraud detection, and debugging.
>
> 3. Get the advertising identifier using the advertisingIdentifier
>      property.

Comment: Any hints on how to get advertisingIdentifier? I am working with Unity3D.

Comment: Any sample code for this would be great, which will get and display the ID on screen.