# Getting hash values from object in swift

Tags: ios, swift, tvos, gamecontroller

In Swift, when I'm typing

```
var controller : GCController
// fetch some data to conbroller
NSLog("Controller: %@",controller)
```

NSLog prints nice

```
Controller: <GCController 0x1700a7680 vendorName='Remote' deviceHash=0x414e6d3d6a8c2215>
```

wheres vendorName is public variable in GCController, but the deviceHash is not. Can I somehow access the value? Even as plain string? From where NSLog takes the values? I tried making NSString in similar format, but it didn't give me the expected results

Comment: What is deviceHash??

Comment: From logs what I can figure out it's assigned by system unique for each controller identifier.

Comment: In that case you can refer this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24760150/how-to-get-a-hashed-device-id-for-testing-admob-on-ios

Comment: You are using swift very Objective-C-like... Why is that? Why not just do print("Controller:" + controller) ?

Comment: I guess, because I am coming from C and Obj-C, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSLog is probably showing you the GCController's debugDescription property whereas print and the likes will show you the description property.

Comment: Is the debugDescritpion available in release build also? Or only in debug one?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be (that should easily be verifiable by simply building in release mode).  It may be a bit risky to rely on the format of the string to extract the hash out of it.  Unlikely as it may sound, Apple could make changes to the framework in a future release and invalidate your string parsing logic.  I believe that when there is no connected controller, that string is a bit different as well.

Comment: Isn't there any C#-like reflection to access this value? I've read that it reflects it's hashValue, it isn't hashtable of all values, right? It's only computing hash for comparisons?