# Show test ads on real device

Tags: swift, admob

This is my code:

```
let request = GADRequest()
request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID, "XXXX2F32d69CCA859FFB559D0FEA3CF6483D08A6"]
adView.load(request)
```

Where XXXX is my UDID of my iPhone. Why do I get real ads and not test ads on my iPhone? Test ads on the simulator works. Thank you. Tried the UDID in uppercase and lowercase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fixed it for me!

Product -> Scheme -> Arguments -> Environment Variables if there is a key: OS_ACTIVITY_MODE, disable/remove it.

Comment: I had the exact same situation and this worked for me, thank you!

Comment: Console when showing " GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers =
              [ "your device" ]"
just copy it to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [admob guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/targeting)

while running the app in device you get the below log

```
<Google> To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices = @[
@"2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b" ];
```

use that id instead of `UDID`.

Comment: Just tried it, not working. I do not get any log message.

Comment: Don't set any test devices and try to run on the device, you will get the log.

Comment: did you remove the last build before testing new build  on real device?

Comment: @SandeepP yes I did not set any test devices, ran it again, no print. And I completely removed the whole app and reinstalled it, still no print, but an ad appears.

Comment: If you are not getting the log then try to generate the ID by referring the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24760150/how-to-get-a-hashed-device-id-for-testing-admob-on-ios

Answer (score 1):

As I understood your, I concate your UDID and  ID in the log. This is wrong.

You this - pure ID :

```
let request = GADRequest()
        request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID, "2F32d69CCA859FFB559D0FEA3CF6483D08A6"]
        adView.load(request)
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/targeting

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand what you mean. The code is exact the same as I provided right? The XXXX was meant to be the beginning of the UDID. The rest of the code is the rest of the UDID.

Comment: I mean remove UDID : 'XXXX' in your code use just string that is shown in the log @J.Doe

Comment: I don't see any logs in my console, thats the problem

Comment: @J.Doe,  just paste mine code, not yours. Do you see the difference?

Comment: Yes, you removed the first 4 charaters from my UDID (XXXX)