# Swift Admob console displays simulator device ID but not when running on iPhone?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, admob

I've implemented Admob into my project however I can't add the test device ID for my iPhone.

Here is the code:

```
let request = GADRequest()
myAd = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-4411736350819540/1731977668")
myAd.delegate = self
myAd.load(request)
```

My device ID isn't showing in the console when I run the app, it just shows an actual ad and not a test ad.

It works fine in Simulator and informs me on how to add the simulator ID.

This is the feedback from console when running on iPhone

```
2017-04-20 01:57:57.311 SpaceShip[2798:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3600000 started
2017-04-20 01:57:57.392 SpaceShip[2798:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled 
2017-04-20 01:57:57.398: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> FIRInstanceID AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote notification handlers. To disable add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO
2017-04-20 01:57:57.397 SpaceShip[2798:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
true
2017-04-20 01:58:05.367 SpaceShip[2798:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics enabled
```

Comment: I downloaded the app "The Identifiers" and added that device ID however test ads didn't display

Comment: what is value of "Limit Ad Tracking" in Settings > Privacy on your phone? If it's ON . try turning it OFF and see if you get id in console

Comment: @AlexIngram you got a solution?? I have exactly the same problem, I even putted a bounty on it but nobody could provide an answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43156883/show-test-ads-on-real-device)... Let me know if/how you fixed this!

Comment: @J.Doe could you try if my solution works?

Comment: @kl.woon I will look right away when I get home!

Comment: @AmodGokhale Already tried that I'm afraid

Comment: @J.Doe The below answer worked for me!! Removing the key that is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check your Product -> Scheme -> Arguments -> Environment Variables if there is a key: `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE`, disable/remove it.

[image]

Comment: Well done!! This worked perfectly. I initially added the key to stop the error message "Skipping input stream" which kept appearing repeatedly in the console after I added sound into the app. Thank you!