# AES 128 Cross-Platform Swift / C#

Tags: c#, swift, aes, rijndaelmanaged

I've been trying to encrypt and decrypt on both iOS and .NET but I haven't been very successful. I've used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27072021/ios-swift-aes-encrypt-and-decrypt) but I get the error:

> Specified initialisation vector (IV) does not match the block size for this algorithm.

Here's my encryption code for Swift using [CryptoSwift](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift):

```
let encrypt = try! "oauth_token".AES_encrypt("my key here (is 32 characters long)", iv: "1234567890123456")

func AES_encrypt(key: String, iv: String) throws -> String {
    let data = self.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let enc = try AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode:.CBC).encrypt(data!.arrayOfBytes(), padding: PKCS7())
    let encData = NSData(bytes: enc, length: Int(enc.count))
    let base64String: String = encData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0));
    let result = String(base64String)
    return result
}
```

And my decryption code for .NET:

```
public static byte[] AES_Decrypt(byte[] bytesToBeDecrypted, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        byte[] decryptedBytes = null;

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                AES.KeySize = 256;
                AES.BlockSize = 128;

                AES.Key = key;
                AES.IV = iv;

                AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(bytesToBeDecrypted, 0, bytesToBeDecrypted.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                decryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }

        return decryptedBytes;
    }



byte[] encrypted_text = Convert.FromBase64String("secret token");
byte[] key = Convert.FromBase64String("32 character key");
byte[] iv = Convert.FromBase64String("0123456789012345");

string plaintext = Convert.ToBase64String(AES_Decrypt(encrypted_text, key, iv));
```

Comment: Is this Xamarin kind of binding to CryptoSwift ? What exactly is "AES_encrypt" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block size is 16 bytes (AES.blockSize). Either you're using old version or your `AES_encrypt()` have some problem (AES_encrypt is not part of CryptoSwift).

Simple example from README:

```
let input: NSData // data to encrypt
let encrypted = try? input.encrypt(AES(key: "secret0key000000", iv:"0123456789012345"))
```

or this

```
// Encrypt string and get Base64 representation of result
let base64: String = try? "my secret string".encrypt(AES(key: "secret0key000000", iv: "0123456789012345"))
```

Comment: I just checked your "AES_encrypt()" and didn't notice any problem with that.

Comment: The issue I get is that C#  says the key or the IV has the wrong size

Comment: @GabrielJones I'm not C# expert, but pretty sure this `Convert.FromBase64String("0123456789012345");` is not what you want to to. "0123456789012345" is probably not base64 encoded value

Comment: I've resolved the problem a different way, thanks anyway!

Comment: @brimstone how did you solve this issue? Would you mind provide your solutions?

Comment: @brimstone please share your solution