# Apple can approve credit card form in my app?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, payment-gateway

I have simple ticket app and in my country `Stripe` or `Paypal` doesn't work. I added my app inside credit card form and I integrated into my own api system . Also I'm using https (Secure Api connection) for credit card payment api.

I want to know when I submit my app to appstore: Appstore will approve my app ? Also how can i encrypt / decrypt my data ?

Comment: Only Apple can say, but probably. You are selling real-world goods, so in-app purchase isn't applicable

Comment: it means you send the your card details to back end and backend do the all progess correct or not

Comment: @Paulw11 i will sell cinema tickets in my app ?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik yes i will do correct

Comment: then apple will approve, main conditon dont save your card details inside the app

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik no i didnt save also i will put there we dont save your card informations

Comment: then fine , apple will approve at the same time use some encryption format for sent the data to server and server decrypt the code

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik can you give me example for this bro ? for encryption and decrypt ? . Im using swift.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because app store submission policy is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/65839) and better addressed by [Apple support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/65839).

Comment: @Peter Copper Jr dont only have my question  policy also have encrypt codes dont touch my question !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is some proprietary service using some proprietary protocol, you can consider using **public key cryptography**. Encrypt data with a one time **AES key**. Send the **encrypted data**. **Encrypt the AES key with your public key** and send it along. The **server decrypts the symmetric AES key with your private key** and thereafter decrypts the data !.

**objective C**

for more information and additional help see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400246/aes-encryption-for-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone)

**Swift**

for swift you can see the [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27072021/aes-encrypt-and-decrypt)

or use

[RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor)

**encrypt**

```
 // Encryption
let data: NSData = ...
let password = "Secret password"
let ciphertext = RNCryptor.encryptData(data, password: password)
```

**decrypt**

```
  // Decryption
do {
let originalData = try RNCryptor.decryptData(ciphertext, password: password)
// ...
} catch {
print(error)
}
```

Comment: ty bro for swift can you give me simple example ?

Comment: TY man ! i will try your idea

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper - welcome bro, this is the sequence , dont forget this dont save any card information in your app

Comment: ty yeah sure. i dont save .