# CryptoSwift with Xcode 9 and AES Decryption

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cocoapods, cryptoswift

I am using Xcode 9.0 and CryptoSwift (0.7.2). I am trying to extend String to decrypt an AES128 encrypted string. I've added CryptoSwift successfully with Pods but I get the following compilation error - what am I doing wrong?

**'PKCS7' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers**

[image]

Here is the extension:

```
import Foundation
import CryptoSwift

extension String {

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27072021/aes-encrypt-and-decrypt
    func aesDecrypt(key: String, iv: String) throws -> String {
        let data = Data(base64Encoded: self)!
        let decrypted = try! AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode: .CBC, padding: PKCS7()).decrypt([UInt8](data))
        let decryptedData = Data(decrypted)
        return String(bytes: decryptedData.bytes, encoding: .utf8) ?? "Could not decrypt"
    }

}
```

Comment: Please check https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift#swift-versions-support whether you are using correct version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've checked out `CryptoSwift`'s documentation, and I found a sample code:

```
let decrypted = try AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode: .CBC, padding: .pkcs7).decrypt(encrypted)
```

and I think it uses `.pkcs7`, instead of `PKCS7()`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helpful!

Comment: Use of unresolved identifier 'encrypted' and Type 'Padding' has no member 'pkcs7

Comment: I have "let enc = try AES(key: key, iv: iv, blockMode: .CBC, padding: .pkcs7).encrypt(data!.bytes)" and now getting error "Expression type 'AES' is ambiguous without more context"