# Encrypt and Decrypt video file after downloading

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, video-encoding

I have a table view that contain video files, I want to download this video file from url and show download progress for every cell , and after finishing downloading, I want to encrypt downloaded video file and when user want to open video I have to decrypt this and show to user. but I did not find a solution for encrypt and decrypt  the video file.
someone have any solution for encrypt and decryption for video file.

Comment: you want to encrypt and decrypt video  right ?

Comment: Can you show your approach that didn't work? Otherwise this will look like asking for code.

Comment: @Tej yes i want to encrypt and decrypt video file

Comment: @AndrasM. i try convert video file to data and use this link for encryption and decryption but that is not work. And I do not know if my solution is right.
  https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27072021/aes-encrypt-and-decrypt

Comment: @AndrasM. i'm using this code for create data from video url:                      do {
      let weatherData = try NSData(contentsOf: url!, options: NSData.ReadingOptions())
      print(weatherData)
    } catch {
      print(error)
    }

Comment: @ava . Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41083395/6880611). 
you might find a proper library

Comment: @Tej decryption result is data that we can convert to video?

Comment: yes @ava. it will return bytes array . you can load video from this byte array .

Comment: @Tej thanks for reply.

Answer (score 2):

Just use iOS build-in Data Protection and the encryption and decryption will be done by iOS automatically on writing the file and reading the file.

Set completeFileProtection when writing the data:

```
static var completeFileProtection: NSData.WritingOptions { get }
```

The file is stored in an encrypted format and may be read from or written to only while the device is unlocked. At all other times, attempts to read and write the file result in failure.

See [iOS Security](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf) Page 11: Encryption and Data Protection, File Data Protection.