# have HMAC SHA256 in pure Swift (Vapor) project

Tags: swift3, hmac, vapor

I am new in Swift based [Vapor](https://github.com/vapor/vapor) backend framework, I just setup the HelloWorld project.

I need to use **HMAC SHA256** algorithm to encrypt data. I searched on internet, and found [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35620960/generating-hmac-sha256-from-byte-array-in-swift), but they are all based on iOS or OSX framework, which uses C library and can be added by `import <CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h>`.

How can I add CommonCrypto or HMAC to my Vapor project? If it is impossible, how can I have a pure swift HMAC Sha256 algorithm? Is there such dependency I can add to *Package.swift* ?

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Vapor 0.17 or later, you should be able to do `import HMAC` and `import SHA2`

From there you can easily create SHA1 hashes using HMAC.

Check out the Crypto package that Vapor uses: https://github.com/vapor/crypto

Additionally, Vapor's default hasher is SHA256 with HMAC. So you can do `drop.hash.make("foo")` and that will work.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to the the [CryptoSwift](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift) project or at least the code from it.

It is a terrible solution on a Mac or iOS device because it does not have hardware support and is hundreds to 1000 times slower than Apple's Common Crypto. But is about as fast as possible in code only.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @zaph answer, and if you want to use more optimized and fast solution, then import OpenSSL in swift using SPM (https://github.com/Zewo/OpenSSL) and then use OpenSSL based HMAC apis.

Reference: https://github.com/yoshiki/HMACHash/blob/master/Sources/HMACHash.swift