# swift 3 md5 hash string (or equivalent) with only built in security module

Tags: md5, swift3, xcode8

I'm looking for a for a way to generate a md5 hash (or equivalent 32 character) string using only the [security module](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security) in Xcode 8 with Swift 3. In other words a method that does **not** require CommonCrypto.

I've only found [one post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099520/commonhmac-in-swift/36974030#36974030) that mentions this approach. This post claims this approach is only for OS X (not iOS).

I know md5 is not super secure but I need compatibility with an older site, so assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with CommonCrypto? It is already available on every device, simple, fast and well tested:

```
extension Data {

    var hexString: String {
        return map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
    }

    var md5: Data {
        var digest = [Byte](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        self.withUnsafeBytes({
            _ = CC_MD5($0, CC_LONG(self.count), &digest)
        })
        return Data(bytes: digest)
    }

}
```

As far as i know the only other possibility to calculate md5 is to add the algorithm by yourself like the one used in [CryptoSwift](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift).