# Swift Playgrounds: MD5 vs "no such module CommonCrypto" +iPad Playgrounds application

Tags: swift, md5, swift-playground, commoncrypto

I want to calculate md5 hash codes from strings in a playgroundbook,
but i got this error message, but i included it as this way:

`import CommonCrypto`

I can not use these: CC_MD5, CC_LONG, CC_MD5_DIGES_LENGTH etc,etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CommonHMAC in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099520/commonhmac-in-swift)

Comment: I want to calculate it in the iPad playgrounds application. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently, it is not possible to do this without a Swift project. Use Swift Project as well as Playground.

Comment: I am newbie, maybe i don't know how it is working, but I want to use it in a playgroundbook, likes the "Learn to code" lessons, not in a Swift Project. Thanks!

Comment: I'd been trying to do this exactly, there is no way Apple haven't implemented classic hash and cryto algorithms in Swift already, this might be a good request for the Swift repository

Comment: Here's [my pure Swift implementation](https://github.com/NikolaiRuhe/SwiftDigest) that does not need CommonCrypto.