# Can't unwrap Optional.None Error, Yet Not Using an Optional

Tags: swift, hmac

I am trying to write an HMAC class in Swift by first writing it in Objective C, and then using a Bridging-Header to make that class available to my Swift code. I'm sorry if I'm pasting too much code, but I'd like to learn why this is happening so I can better understand intefacing Swift and Objective C, and how I can resolve the error I'm getting. The "TBGHMAC.calculateWithAlgorithm: forKey: and Data:" function produces a "fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None" error.

Starting from the top, here is the snippet in my Swift code that calls the Swift code

```
    let key : String = "" // start with empty string"
    let data : String = "" // start with empty string"

    let signature : String = TBGHMAC.calculateWithAlgorithm(HMACAlgorithm.SHA256, forKey: key, andData: data)

    println(signature)
```

and here is the TBGHMAC header file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>

@interface TBGHMAC : NSObject


typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, HMACAlgorithm)
{
SHA1,
MD5,
SHA256,
SHA384,
SHA512,
SHA224
};

+ (NSString *)calculateWithAlgorithm:(HMACAlgorithm)algorithm forKey:(NSString*)key andData:(NSString *)data;

+ (NSInteger)digestLengthForAlgorithm:(HMACAlgorithm)algorithm;

@end
```

and finally here is the implementation file

```
+ (NSString *)calculateWithAlgorithm:(HMACAlgorithm)algorithm forKey:(NSString *)key andData:(NSString *)data
{

    NSUInteger keyNumberOfBytes = [key lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    void *keyBuffer = malloc(keyNumberOfBytes);
    NSUInteger keyUsedLength = 0;
    NSRange keyRange = NSMakeRange(0, [key length]);
    BOOL keyResult = [key getBytes:keyBuffer maxLength:keyNumberOfBytes usedLength:&keyUsedLength encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding options:0 range:keyRange remainingRange:NULL];

    NSUInteger dataNumberOfBytes = [data lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
    void *dataBuffer = malloc(dataNumberOfBytes);
    NSUInteger dataUsedLength = 0;
    NSRange dataRange = NSMakeRange(0, [data length]);
    BOOL dataResult = [data getBytes:dataBuffer maxLength:dataNumberOfBytes usedLength:&dataUsedLength encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding options:0 range:dataRange remainingRange:NULL];

    NSInteger digestLength = [self digestLengthForAlgorithm:algorithm];
    unsigned char hmac[digestLength];

    CCHmac(algorithm, &keyBuffer, strlen(keyBuffer), &dataBuffer, strlen(dataBuffer), &hmac);

    NSData *hmacBytes = [NSData dataWithBytes:hmac length:sizeof(hmac)];

    NSString* returnStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:hmacBytes encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    free(keyBuffer);
    free(dataBuffer);

    return returnStr;
}

+ (NSInteger)digestLengthForAlgorithm:(HMACAlgorithm)algorithm
{
    switch (algorithm)
    {
        case MD5: return CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH;
        case SHA1: return CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH;
        case SHA224: return CC_SHA224_DIGEST_LENGTH;
        case SHA256: return CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH;
        case SHA384: return CC_SHA384_DIGEST_LENGTH;
        case SHA512: return CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH;
        default: return 0;
    }
}

@end
```

Please point out why this error is coming up, and how I can resolve it. I do not understand how this error is arising, because I'm not using any Optionals, and Xcode isn't trying to correct me into using Optionals.

Comment: Everything passed from ObjC to Swift is an Optional, it might help to read the docs on how to use ObjC with Swift:https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Objective-C method

```
+ (NSString *)calculateWithAlgorithm:(HMACAlgorithm)algorithm forKey:(NSString*)key andData:(NSString *)data;
```

is exposed to Swift as

```
class func calculateWithAlgorithm(algorithm: HMACAlgorithm, forKey key: String!, andData data: String!) -> String!
```

It returns an *(implicitly unwrapped) optional* string because the `NSString` returned by the Objective-C method may be `nil`.

Converting the return value to a `String` in

```
let signature : String = BGHMAC.calculateWithAlgorithm(...)
```

causes a runtime exception if the return value is `nil` ("no value"). You should therefore test the return value
before using it:

```
let signature : String! = TBGHMAC.calculateWithAlgorithm(HMACAlgorithm.SHA256, forKey: key, andData: data)
if signature {
    println(signature)
} else {
    println("failed")
}
```

But why does `calculateWithAlgorithm()` return `nil`? The problem is here:

```
NSString* returnStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:hmacBytes encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

A message digest is a quite arbitrary sequence of bytes, and cannot be interpreted
as an UTF-8 string, therefore `returnStr` is nil.

To solve your problem, you could for example convert the message digest to
a string using the *Base64 encoding*:

```
NSString* returnStr = [hmacBytes base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

Comment: Thank you @Martin R, though I have a couple follow up questions.

1. When the compiler converts Obj-C into Swift, and makes the parameters of type String! does the "String!" indicate that the string coming in is a regular optional, or that it is an implicitly unwrapped optional?

2. Why choose base64encoding, does UTF-8 not use fixed-width character values? What is the customary way to output a string of hex digits from an NSData type?

Comment: 1) You are right, the return value is an implicitly unwrapped optional, I have updated the answer accordingly. - 2) UTF-8 uses 1, 2, 3 or 4 bytes to encode a Unicode character. An "arbitrary" sequence of bytes is usually not a valid UTF-8 sequence. Base64 is one customary way, another is to convert each bytes to hex. (Base64 is shorter.)

Comment: This actually doesn't work, since base64EncodedStringWithOptions: returns (NSData *), and so I'm not really any closer to converting from NSData to a NSString.

Comment: @almel: That is strange. In https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/base64EncodedStringWithOptions: the method is documented as `- (NSString *)base64EncodedStringWithOptions:(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions)options`, so it returns an NSString. And actually I tested the code before posting the answer. Perhaps you mixed it up with `base64EncodedDataWithOptions`?

Comment: Oh no I see now I was using base64EncodedDataWithOptions:, rather than String. Sorry about that. Do you have any clues why my HMAC method is not passing any of the test vectors listed on the HMAC RFC and other test sites?

Comment: @almel: I am pretty sure that NSUnicodeStringEncoding should be NSUTF8StringEncoding in your code. Apart from that, I do not know why you don't get the expected result, and I do not have the time at present to analyze your code in detail, sorry.

Comment: Just for completion's sake, I eventually found the correct Obj-C code in the answer to this SO post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458917/need-to-generate-hmac-sha256-hash-in-objective-c-as-in-java